# How web page automatically identify country?

Tags: c#, asp.net, geolocation, country

I am working in ASP.net and C# . Currently i am designing a signup page for my web application. On that page there is a field "Country", user can specify his country using drop-down list. Now i want to automatically detect user's country and then pre select that country in drop-down list. How do i identify user country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some kind of IP geolocation database to map the users IP address to a country.  There are plenty of services and data files online, just google for geo IP lookup.

EDIT just did a quick google for you [this](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoIPCountryCSV.zip) should give you the data you need.

Answer (score 3):

the users browser already sends you his prevered language and localization with the HTTP-Header

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

if you want to change the CurrentCulture based on this information you can add the following to your web.config

```
<system.web>    
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
    ...snip...
```